# AngularJS: Function call in ternary operator conditional check

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ternary-operator

My HAML file:

```
%pipes-autocomplete{:model =>"filter.value",:option => "validate_option(filter)" ? "dependant(filter)" : "filter.option"}
```

My Coffee Script:

```
  $scope.validate_option =(filter)->
     console.log "called validate_option"
     if filter.hasOwnProperty('option') && filter.option.indexOf('dependant') > -1
       return true
     else
      return false
  $scope.dependant =(cal)->
    return "choosed"
```

In the ternary operator I'm trying to call the validate_option function defined in my angular controller.But the function is not getting called.Can someone help me with this problem.

Comment: As you put it now the ternary operator will consider the string to be true (just because it is not an empty one). Try with `"validate_option(filter) ? dependant(filter) : filter.option"` (all in one string), so that you defer the execution of the ternary operator to when the string is evaluated.

Comment: @trincot Thank you so much. It works fine.I am a newbie to angular.And my doubts got cleared with your explanation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you put it in the question, the ternary operator will consider the string `"validate_option(filter)"` to be `true` (just because it is not an empty one).

Instead put the ternary operator inside the string:

```
"validate_option(filter) ? dependant(filter) : filter.option"
```

That way you defer the execution of the ternary operator to when the string is actually evaluated.